# Infinite number of primes congruent to 5 mod 6

Tags: number-theory

1. In the proof that there are an infinite number of primes equivalent to 5 mod 6, we suppose by way of contradiction that $\{5, p_1, . . . , p_r\}$ is the complete list, and we consider the integer $m=6(p_1 ·p_2···p_r)+5$.

b. Show that at least one prime factor $q$ of $m$ is congruent to $5 \bmod 6$.

I don't understand why $p_j$ cannot be congruent to $1 \bmod 6$.

Answer (score 2):

The product of numbers that are $1$ modulo $6$ is again $1\pmod{6}$. If $m$ consisted of primes of this form only, then their product, $m$, would also be of this form. But in fact, $m$ isn't of this form, $$m=6(p_1\cdots p_r)+5=5\pmod{6}.$$ Hence there must be at least one prime factor of type $5\pmod{6}$.

(To complete the proof, one should add that this prime factor, call it $q$, is not one of the $p_i$'s. Otherwise $q$ would divide $m$ and also $6p_1\cdots p_r$, so must divide $5$.)

Comment: maybe this is a stupid clarification but I am unable to understand why 1 mod 6 is introduced in this proof and what do you mean by "But it isn't".

Comment: @Mai If all prime factors of $m$ are $\equiv 1\pmod{\!6}$ then so too is their product $m$. But $\,m\equiv -1\pmod{\!6}$ so $m$ must have some prime factor $\not\equiv 1\pmod{\!6}$ (hence $\equiv -1\pmod{\!6},\,$ by $m$ coprime to $2,3,\,$ i.e. prime $p> 3$ implies $\,p\equiv \pm1\pmod{\!6})\ $

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that there are infinitely many primes congruent to $5$ modulo $6$. In order to prove that, we assume for contradiction that there are only finitely many of them. The list $\{5, p_q, p_2, \ldots, p_r\}$ is the complete list of all primes congruent to $5$ modulo $6$. An element $p_j$ in this list cannot be congruent to $1$ modulo $6$ because if that were the case then $p_j$ wouldn't be in this list.